# Impossible to run a Laravel application inside a docker container due to permissions issues

Tags: php, laravel, docker, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

I have a `docker-compose` configuration that defines three containers I use for one of my applications inside of an Ubuntu 16.04 instance:

- A nginx container,
- A mysql container,
- And a PHP container that is slightly customised to include `composer` and `phpunit`, and is derived from a base `php74:fpm-alpine` directory. The working directory in this container is `/var/www`.

I define a single volume that maps from my application to inside the container in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
app-php:
  volumes:
    - ./src:/var/www
```

Whenever I try and run my Laravel application, I receive:

`The stream or file "/var/www/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

Obviously Laravel cannot write or read to this file, but I can't figure out why. The entire application directory has the following permissions settings:

```
$ la -la

-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser www-data    213 Dec 31 07:07 aFile
drwxrwsr-x 12 myuser www-data   4096 Dec 31 07:07 aDirectory
```

This was accomplished with the following commands:

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data myuser
// myuser is now a member of the www-data group.
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```

None of this works. The **only** way I've been able to make my application run is my executing `sudo chmod -R 777`, *which is not an acceptable solution*. Neither `775` or `755` solve the situation.

This leads to my overall question: **What alterations do I need to make, either to my docker configuration, or my permissions configuration on the host system, to have my application run?**

Comment: you need to understand what's the system username which is owning the current php process and then set permissions accordingly. You can empirically test it via allowing write to everyone chmod 777, log anything new, check who's the owner of the new log file....

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it has nothing to do with user permission in Host file system, rather it feels like some issue with permission with USER used inside docker container. See if following link help you -
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user

Comment: If this were the case, why does altering the permissions to `777` from the host allow the application to run?

Answer (score -1):

You need to set read/write permission on folder `storage` in order to allow laravel to create new files there such as `.log`

Try to run change owner of the directory to `www-data`:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage`

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, this does not work, nor is an acceptable solution.

Comment: please add `ls -al ./src`

Comment: @reactingtoangularvues I would like to see permission for storage directory.